# Defining a class with no default constructor inside a struct

Tags: c++, class, struct, embedded, tensorflow-lite

I've got an issue where I'm having to use a C++ library in an embedded system. The library (Tensorflow Lite for microcontrollers) is designed for embedded systems and for use without malloc/free, however the examples of using it define everything on the stack and there is no default constructor available.

Defining on the stack doesn't work in my application because I need to be able to initialise it in a function which will then exit. What I need is to be able to allocate a memory area (with my own allocator) that contains everything I need and then initialise everything in that memory area.

I've tried to boil this down to a bare minimum example:

```
// This is a third party library
class OtherClass {};
class MyClass {
 private:
   OtherClass &c;
 public:
    MyClass(OtherClass &c) : c(c) {};
};

// My code
typedef struct {
  OtherClass otherClass;
  MyClass myClass;
} MyAllocatedData;

char dataIsSomewhere[sizeof(MyAllocatedData)];
MyAllocatedData *pData = (MyAllocatedData *)dataIsSomewhere;

int main() {
  // dataIsSomewhere gets allocated somewhere on demand
  // now we want to initialise everything
  pData->myClass = MyClass(pData->otherClass);  
  return 0;
}
```

The compilation of this fails with:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:20:45: error: use of deleted function ‘MyClass& MyClass::operator=(MyClass&&)’
   pData->myClass = MyClass(pData->otherClass);
                                             ^
test.cpp:3:7: note: ‘MyClass& MyClass::operator=(MyClass&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class MyClass {
       ^~~~~~~
test.cpp:3:7: error: non-static reference member ‘OtherClass& MyClass::c’, can’t use default assignment operator
```

Is there a nice way around this? Patching the library would be a possibility but I'd rather not.

Maybe I could define my own `new` operator for `MyClass` which allocated it in the correct place? It doesn't seem ideal though.

Comment: Use initializer list.

Comment: and placement new should be used instead of casting buffer. But regular class seems to do the job.

Comment: I don't really get how this would work better/different if things were allocated on the stack. But placement-new is probably all you need to get everything to work. I'll echo the comment above that casting to `MyAllocatedData*` is not enough to use that memory buffer the way you want, you should also placement-new a `MyAllocatedData` instance into that storage so that a `MyAllocatedData` object actually lives there (everything else is UB).

Comment: Thanks! The example is intentionally very stripped down, but placement new looks spot on. I had no idea this even existed. I'm testing now and I'll report back

Comment: besides using placement new as suggested, you should also be careful with alignment - you might want to use [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage)

Comment: Using `MyClass` for third party is misleading.

Comment: Yes, that's bad form - purely because I hacked up some test code and then added the comments later. Unfortunately given all the answers reference it, it's probably more confusing to change it right now

Comment: I'm actually embedding this in a JS runtime on a microcontroller (Espruino). Probably a good 95% of users will never use it and since RAM is at a premium I want to only allocate the data when it's needed (and because it's basically running a JS-centric mini-RTOS it's not quite as easy as using bog standard `malloc/new`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proper contructor:

```
struct MyAllocatedData
{
  MyAllocatedData() : otherClass(), myClass(otherClass) {}

  OtherClass otherClass;
  MyClass myClass;
};
```

And then

```
int main() {
  MyAllocatedData data;
  // ...
}
```

or if you need to place it in memory, use placement new:

```
MyAllocatedData* pData = new (dataIsSomewhere) MyAllocatedData{};
```

Comment: Thanks! This would be great for the example, however the example I posted was deliberately simplified. The actual issue I have (involving `tflite::MicroInterpreter`) requires more arguments that couldn't be supplied inside `MyAllocatedData` - so while i could create a class to handle it, things get complicated quite quickly as I need to allocate a variable size block of data on the end of the struct as well. `placement new` seems like the trick I need.

Comment: Accepting your answer because I believe you were first to post the suggestion as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use placement new to create an object in a given location:

```
new (&pData->myClass) MyClass(pData->otherClass);
```

Comment: And of course, you then have to `delete` what you `new`ed.

Comment: the same should probably be done for the `OtherClass` instance as well, otherwise it remains uninitialized

Comment: This looks spot on for what I need, thanks! However, I do get `static void MyClass::operator delete(void*)’ is private within this context` errors (because in tflite the 'delete' operator is defined as a private empty method). Any idea how I could work around that? For now I modified tflite's source to make `delete` public and it's fine, but obviously it'd be better if I could get away without patching source - and I don't really understand why `delete` is even called

Comment: @MaxLanghof Absolutely not in this case. Placement new only creates a new object; the destructor will take care of its destruction.

Comment: @GordonWilliams You shouldn’t use `delete`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof : you shouldn't `delete`, but you *do* need to call the destructor manually : `pData->myClass.~MyClass();`

Comment: My issue is that I'm not using `delete` at all, but the compiler is still complaining that it isn't public (it won't happen in the example, but it does with tflite because the delete op is private)

Comment: I stand corrected! Sorry for the incorrect information @GordonWilliams!